# What are the benefits and drawbacks of using ETag vs LastModified as a CDN cache validator?

Tags: http, azure, cdn, etags

I'm reading [this article on Azure CDN.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-manage-expiration-of-cloud-service-content/) I can either control caching with:

1. An ETag
2. Last Modified
3. Default heuristics

What are the benefits and drawbacks of the first two choices? Does it matter?

Places where one might work vs the other could be:

- Cross domain calls
- Private browsing
- IFrames
- Ajax

... where that data is either visible by those methods, and not the others.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid to use in whatever scenario.
`eTag` is newer so it is considered best practice to use that instead of `last-modified`, however it is up to you.
Here is the `MS Docs` page explaining that `eTag` takes precedence over `last-modified` in which system interprets it:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-how-caching-works#cdn-caching

Answer (score 0):

Let me make two real-life assumptions:

- you cannot easily customize the code that generates `ETag` or `Last-Modified` for you
- you are serving some static files

with this in mind, the most obvious difference is that for files, it's easy for you to either accidentally or purposely change the modification date, thus changing `Last-Modified` header. (You could even, gasp, return to an earlier date.) In general case, you cannot impact `ETag` so easily. Good or bad? Depends on your use case. If the code that generates `ETag` is decent, I'd say it is better suited to a general use case aka just-works-out-of-the-box-dont-touch-the-knobs. But to know whether it's decent requires testing, especially testing upgrades and downgrades.

ETag is good for content that changes more than once per second (example: a heavily used chat), because Last-Modified only supports 1-second granularity.

ETag for compressed response should be re-generated by your server, it cannot be copied from uncompressed one. But it's much less CPU usage than compressing anyway.

With CORS, youu have `Last-Modified` for free, but to have `eTag` your server needs to support an extra header `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the use case...

e.g. if you have a page that should show e.g. the time or time elapsed from anything, than last modified would be the best solution (because you are asking for the time).

but e.g. if you have dynamical created content, and you e.g. change some scripts what resuls in change modification date, but the delivered content is still identical.
This szenario would result in useless reloading caches, while eTag would say "Content identical, so it results in the same eTag.

Similar situations could even occour when your modification time of static files is changed, but content is the same. E.g. when you copy some files on a new disk (what results in updateing the time)